# Getting a segfault using realloc

Tags: c, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to solve the following question that recently appeared in my friends' university exams (the exams are now over and papers are released).

> Develop a C program to manage a playlist of songs, where each song has a title and a duration (in seconds). Use two separate dynamically allocated arrays to store the titles and durations. Implement user-defined functions to add, remove, update, and display the playlist information using pointer arithmetic. [10 marks]

I made the following attempt:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

const size_t MAX_NAME_LENGTH = 20;
size_t number_of_songs = 0;

char* names_of_songs;
int* durations;

void add(char* name_of_song, int duration) {
    number_of_songs++;

    names_of_songs = realloc(name_of_song, MAX_NAME_LENGTH * number_of_songs);
    durations = realloc(durations, number_of_songs * sizeof(int));

    int start_location = ((number_of_songs - 1) * MAX_NAME_LENGTH) + 1;
    char* name_location = &name_of_song[start_location];

    strncpy(name_location, name_of_song, MAX_NAME_LENGTH);

    names_of_songs[start_location + strlen(name_of_song) + 1] = 0;
    durations[number_of_songs - 1] = duration;
}

void display() {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < number_of_songs; i++) {
        int position_in_name = 0;
        int start_location = (i * MAX_NAME_LENGTH) + 1;
        char character = 1;

        printf("Name: ");
        while (character != 0) {
            character = names_of_songs[start_location++];
            printf("%c", character);
        }

        printf(", Duration: %d sec\n", durations[i]);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    names_of_songs = malloc(1);
    durations = malloc(1);

    display();
    add("Something", 2);
    display();
    add("Something else", 32);
    display();
    add("boring song", 4);
    display();

    free(names_of_songs);
    free(durations);

    return 0;
}
```

When I run it, I get a segmentation fault. Using my debugger, it seems to happen the first time `realloc()` is run, when `add()` tries to adjust for the new songs title. What is happening and how do I fix it?

Additionally, how would I debug something like this?

Comment: You can't `realloc` something that wasn't previously `malloc`ed (or `calloc`ed).  Did you mean to code `realloc(name_of_songs` rather than `realloc(name_of_song`?

Comment: @G.M. I call `malloc()` in `main()` to make sure it has been called once for that pointer.

Comment: `name_of_song` and `names_of_songs`. That's a really bad choice of variable names, since it's too easy to use one went you meant to use the other. The first `realloc` in `add` is using the wrong variable.

Comment: You don't need the `malloc(1)` calls in `main`. If you pass a `NULL` pointer to `realloc`, it will act just like `malloc`. The two global pointers (`names_of_songs` and `durations`) will both be set to `NULL` when the program starts.

Comment: that was indeed the problem @user3386109. thanks! I've now used completely different names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `relloc()` is used to resize dynamic memory.  The easiest fix is to just allow the default 0 initialization for global variables.
2. Assign the return value of `realloc()` to a temporary, otherwise you leak memory if `realloc()` fails.
3. Incorrect variable used in the first `realloc()` `name_of_song` when you meant `names_of_songs`.
4. Use symbolic constant instead of a const value.  You need the former when allocating memory on the stack, otherwise they will become VLAs.
5. The `+ 1` in start location is wrong.
6. Removed the `display()` after each `add()` as it was confusing (to me).
7. (Not fixed) For `names_of_songs` consider using an array of char pointers (i.e. `char **names_of_songs`): `names_of_songs[number_of_songs] = strndup(name_of_songs, MAX_NAME_LENGTH)` which is easier and you don't have wasted space.
8. (Not fixed) If you really want to use a char array, consider indexing into it with a pointer to an char array `(*p)[MAX_NAME_LENGTH]` so the compiler scales the pointer for you.
9. `display()`: It is easier to just print a string instead of each character individually.  Then you can combine all the `printf()` calls into one.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_NAME_LENGTH 20
size_t number_of_songs;
char* names_of_songs;
int* durations;

void add(char* name_of_song, int duration) {
    char *tmp = realloc(names_of_songs, MAX_NAME_LENGTH * (number_of_songs + 1));
    if(!tmp) {
        printf("malloc failed\n");
        return;
    }
    names_of_songs = tmp;
    strncpy(names_of_songs + number_of_songs * MAX_NAME_LENGTH, name_of_song, MAX_NAME_LENGTH);
    names_of_songs[number_of_songs * MAX_NAME_LENGTH + strlen(name_of_song)] = '\0';

    int *tmp2 = realloc(durations, sizeof *tmp2 * (number_of_songs + 1));
    if(!tmp2) {
        printf("malloc failed\n");
        return;
    }
    durations = tmp2;
    durations[number_of_songs] = duration;
    number_of_songs++;
}

void display() {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < number_of_songs; i++)
        printf("Name: %s, Duration %d sec\n",
            names_of_songs + i * MAX_NAME_LENGTH,
            durations[i]
        );
}

int main() {
    add("Something", 2);
    add("Something else", 32);
    add("boring song", 4);
    display();
    free(names_of_songs);
    free(durations);
}
```

example output:

```
Name: Something, Duration: 2 sec
Name: Something else, Duration: 32 sec
Name: boring song, Duration: 4 sec
```